# jwplayer playlist is not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, jwplayer, playlists

hi all,

```
              jwplayer("XXX").setup({
               playlist: [
                 {file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$youtube_id1.'"},
                  {file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$youtube_id2.'"}
                  ],
                width: "560",
                primary: "flash", 
                height: "315",
                image: "/hqdefault.jpg", 
                autostart: "true",
                skin: "/vapor.xml"
              });
```

i have a problem, i cannot play this playlist as a whole in mobile, only playing the 1st video then stop.
in desktop version is working well.

i use jwplayer 6 premium

anyone can help me? im stuck here:(
thank

Note: if i changed them to local files(videos), it works...

Comment: It seems like you are following the structure of - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29247/basic-inline-playlist, do you have a link?

Comment: @EthanLongTail Hi Ethan, thank, hereby the link: bit.ly/17p6drT
i added the repeat: "always", but only repeat the 1st video.

Comment: Ah, this is because we just fall back to the default YouTube player for devices, so no playlist shows up at all. We plan on addressing this in a future JW6 release though.

Comment: @EthanLongTail i see, so if 2 youtube files as a playlist it will not showing at all, but if the local files ( not you tube, it will be ok?)
is it correct what i understand? may i know when its gonna be in JW6? cause need to say it to my client :) thank

Comment: Yes, if you use non YouTube, it will work. It will be in JW6, but no ETA yet (for YouTube), most likely 6.6+, at least a few months out at this point.

Comment: @EthanLongTail great, looking forward to it :).. i need to search for other solution, any advise? lol

Comment: I would use your host hosted mp4s instead of youtube for the time being then.