# Does jwplayer support playlist including youtube videos on mobile?

Tags: youtube-api, jwplayer6

Ethan JWPlayer (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645000/ethan-jwplayer) mentioned (here: [jwplayer playlist is not working in mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251702/jwplayer-playlist-is-not-working-in-mobile)) that playlists are not supported with youtube videos on mobile, but it would be supported in the future.

Is it supported yet? If not what's the plan (ETA)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
            file: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL895D164BB097AA0F",
            flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
            volume: 80,
            width: 465,
            stretching: 'fill'
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The playlist url must be in this format:**

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL895D164BB097AA0F
```